# Exclude value from query where already returned in rows above

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am writing a query which will be used to populate a report used for putting away stock in a warehouse.

The report has 3 parameters, a source stock location, source bin number and a destination stock location.

The stock will be currently held in source stock location and bin number.

The destination stock location is where the stock needs to be moved to.

Each Variant has a default bin number in each stock location. 
Multiple variants can have the same default bin number.

Bin numbers may not be alphabetical around the warehouse, and so each bin number is assigned a walk route, as the most efficient walking route around the warehouse.

The report will look at the default bin number associated with the item in the destination stock location, and if empty, offer that as the put away suggestion.
If the default bin number is not empty, it will look for the next available empty bin in the destination stock location (where walk route is higher than default bin), and then offer that as the put away suggestion.

The query works fine, and does exactly that, however it is reporting the same bin as previous "NextBinNo" suggestions in rows above.

How can I get the OUTER APPLY NextBinNo to filter out any previously suggested bins in higher rows of data? Also if two items have the same default bin number, it should use the NextBinNo for the second row with this default bin no.

My current query:

```
Select
row_number() Over(Order by DestSL.sl_id) as RowNo,
Stock_location.sl_name,
bin_number.bn_bin_number,
variant_detail.vad_variant_code,
variant_detail.vad_description,
variant_transaction_header.vth_current_quantity,
variant_transaction_header.vth_batch_number,
purchase_order_header.poh_order_number,
supplier_detail.sd_ow_account,
DestSL.sl_id as 'DestinationSLID',
DestSL.sl_name as 'DestinationStockLocation',
DestDefaultBin.bn_bin_number as 'DestinationDefaultBin',
DestDefaultBin.bn_walk_route as 'DestinationDefaultWalkRoute',
isnull(DestDefaultBinQty.BinQty,0) as QtyInDefaultBin,
NextBinNo.NextBinNo as 'NextBinNo',
NextBinNo.NextWalkRoute as 'NextBinWalkRoute',
isnull(NextBinNo.BinQty,0) as 'NextBinQty',


case when DestDefaultBin.bn_bin_number is null
then 'Not Stocked in This Location'
Else 
    case when isnull(DestDefaultBinQty.BinQty,0) > 0
    then 
        case when NextBinNo.NextBinNo is NULL
        then 'No Free Bin'
        Else NextBinNo.NextBinNo
        End
    Else DestDefaultBin.bn_bin_number 
    End
End as 'Put Away Destination'



From variant_transaction_header
join bin_number on bin_number.bn_id = variant_transaction_header.vth_bn_id
join stock_location on stock_location.sl_id = variant_transaction_header.vth_sl_id
join variant_detail on variant_detail.vad_id = variant_transaction_header.vth_vad_id
join transaction_type on transaction_Type.tt_id = variant_transaction_header.vth_tt_id
left join purchase_order_line on purchase_order_line.pol_id = variant_transaction_header.vth_pol_id
left join purchase_order_header on purchase_order_header.poh_id = purchase_order_line.pol_poh_id
left join supplier_detail on supplier_detail.sd_id = purchase_order_header.poh_sd_id

join stock_location DestSL on DestSL.sl_id = @DestinationStockLoc
left join variant_stock_location DestVSL on DestVSL.vsl_vad_id = variant_detail.vad_id and DestVSL.vsl_sl_id = DestSL.sl_id
left join bin_number DestDefaultBin on DestDefaultBin.bn_id = DestVSL.vsl_bn_id

left join
    (select sum(variant_transaction_header.vth_current_quantity) as BinQty,
    variant_transaction_header.vth_bn_id
    from variant_transaction_header
    join transaction_type on transaction_Type.tt_id = variant_transaction_header.vth_tt_id
    Where  variant_transaction_header.vth_current_quantity > 0
    and transaction_type.tt_transaction_type = 'IN' and transaction_Type.tt_update_current_qty = 1
    Group by variant_transaction_header.vth_bn_id) as DestDefaultBinQty on DestDefaultBinQty.vth_bn_id = DestDefaultBin.bn_id



Outer Apply
    (select top 1
    row_number() Over(Order by NextBin.bn_bin_number) as RowNo,
    NextBin.bn_bin_number as NextBinNo,
    NextBin.bn_walk_route as NextWalkRoute,
    BinQty.BinQty
    from 
    Stock_location DestSL
    Join bin_number NextBin on NextBin.bn_sl_id = DestSL.sl_id
        left join
        (select sum(variant_transaction_header.vth_current_quantity) as BinQty,
        variant_transaction_header.vth_bn_id
        from variant_transaction_header
        join transaction_type on transaction_Type.tt_id = variant_transaction_header.vth_tt_id
        Where  variant_transaction_header.vth_current_quantity > 0
        and transaction_type.tt_transaction_type = 'IN' and transaction_Type.tt_update_current_qty = 1
        Group by variant_transaction_header.vth_bn_id) as BinQty on BinQty.vth_bn_id = NextBin.bn_id
    Where NextBin.bn_sl_id = @DestinationStockLoc
    and NextBin.bn_walk_route > DestDefaultBin.bn_walk_route
    And isnull(BinQty.BinQty,0) = 0
    order by NextBin.bn_walk_route, nextbin.bn_bin_number) as NextBinNo


where variant_transaction_header.vth_current_quantity > 0
and transaction_type.tt_transaction_type = 'IN' and transaction_Type.tt_update_current_qty = 1
and stock_location.sl_id = @SourceStockLoc and bin_number.bn_id = @SourceBinNo
```

You can see my current results below:

Row2 is using the NextBinNo as the default bin has stock.
Row3 is also suggesting using AA08A2 as the next bin.

Row 6 is currently suggesting AA01A2 but that has already been suggested in Row1.

[image]

Comment: Is there some reason a WHERE NOT EXISTS() clause wouldn't solve this?

Comment: How can I use that to reference only rows above as the query is running?

Comment: hmm, yes, good question.   Maybe by testing whether the conditions that produced the previous rows would have resulted in the same bin that the query is wanting to use now?   I haven't read your entire query, but the pseudo-logic would be "where RowValue < ValueForThisRow AND BinForThatValue = BinForThisValue"

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer this, in the end I could not achieve what I wanted directly in SQL.

The data is ultimately being returned to a report writer which can run Visual Basic code.

I had to execute the `NextBinNo` sub query separately in VB.

In VB I can define a string which contains a list of all the "used" bin numbers and so on each row this is referenced in the `WHERE` of the query to check it has not been used in a row above.

I could then return this value as a new column dynamically inserted in the dataset at run time.